# OneWay binding for ToggleButton's IsChecked property in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, togglebutton

I have a `ToggleButton` with its `IsChecked` property bound to a property using a OneWay binding.

```
<ToggleButton
    Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The `SomeCommand` toggles the boolean `SomeProperty` value, and a `PropertyChanged` event is raised for `SomeProperty`.

If I change `SomeProperty` in my viewmodel the `ToggleButton` depresses correctly. However if I click the `ToggleButton` the binding seems to get lost and the button no longer gets checked according to the value of `SomeProperty`. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: What does your SomeCommand do?  I have a number of ToggleButtons that do the same thing, with the same kind of binding, and all SomeCommand does is negate the current value of SomeProperty.

Comment: SomeProperty was actually a different type and I was using a converter to change it to a boolean. I left that out to make the question simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design when using oneway data binding. Add the attached property PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to your binding and you will see when it gets disconnected. This link describes the problem as well (without offering any solution): [Debugging Data Binding in WPF](http://jimmangaly.blogspot.com/2009/04/debugging-data-binding-in-wpf.html)

The way I normally solve it is to use a command for user interaction and code behind to change the control appearance because of some changed properties.

Comment: Why this answer got accepted? It doesn't solve the problem (which exists and can be easily reproduced).

Answer (score 13):

There is a simple and elegant way to solve the original poster's problem - replacing IsChecked property of the ToggleButton with an attachable property that will set IsChecked of the button in its change handler:

```
namespace TBFix
{
  public class TBExtender
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", 
                                          typeof(bool),
                                          typeof(TBExtender),
                                          new PropertyMetadata(OnChanged));

    public static bool GetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj)
    {
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject o,
                                  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      ToggleButton tb = o as ToggleButton;
      if (null != tb)
        tb.IsChecked = (bool)args.NewValue;
    }
  }
}
```

XAML then will look like this:

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}"
              TBFix:TBExtender.IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty,
                                                   Mode=OneWay}" />
```

EDIT: The OP solution does not work, because when the button is pressed the IsChecked property is set in the code (this is the way MS implemented ToggleButton control) - setting the property removes the binding from it and so it stops working.

By using attached property we can overcome this problem because it is never assigned a value in code and so the bindings stays intact.

Comment: Hi Alex,  Thanks for providing the elegant solution, it works for me. but I don't understand how it works.  Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I've added few words on the idea behind my solution. You can read more about attached properties on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This is indeed elegant!

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge Sinatr is correct regarding the 'desync' that occurs, at least in newer frameworks.

Another simple way around the issue is to remove the mode=oneway and implement an empty setter.  Ex:

```
    bool _MyIsEnabled;
    public bool MyIsEnabled
    {
        get { return _MyIsEnabled; }
        set { }
    }
```

With this binding setup you can you change the value of the backing variable from your command binding function, or from whether you need to.  Just remember to call RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: Love this easy workaround - a little hacky, but way simpler than creating custom controls

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem.

It is **not** *"the binding seems to get lost"* (unless it's earlier frameworks problems). Binding continues working and can be easily proved by changing property outside of **that command** (e.g. in handler of another button click event/command).

The problem is what `IsChecked` can be changed in two ways: 1) binding (when value of `SomeProperty` is changed button will be updated 2) user (if user press button he will change `IsChecked`, but binding is `OneWay` so `SomeProperty` will not be updated).

So you may have **desync** occurs when `SomeProperty == false` but button `IsChecked == true` or vice-versa.

To optimize performance binding mechanism is checking if new value is different from current. So if desync occurs and you try to update `SomeProperty` with the value which it already have, then nothing will happens.

Workaround is simple: update property in 2 steps

```
SomeProperty = !set;
SomeProperty = set;
```

where `set` is the value you need (e.g. opposite to current `SomeProperty`).

Answer (score 0):

I think what the problem boils down to is a conflict between the command and the `IsChecked` binding. My solution was to change my viewmodel to expose a `bool?` and bind that to the `IsChecked` property. I did not bind a command to the `ToggleButton`. Elsewhere in my code where I want to toggle the property I use `SomeCommand`.