# Binding DataGrid Expander when using ListCollectionView

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to get all the DataGrid Expanders to open and close using a open/close button like the example below. Problem is when I'm using a single boolean to bind to this will break when I'm opening/closing a single expander.

I'm using a ListCollectionView to set the GroupingDescription.

I guess I'm looking for a solution to somehow get the Expander to play nice?

[image: Example]

### View

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.Expanded, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <!-- label -->
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

### ViewModel

```
public bool Expanded
{
    get { return _expanded; }
    set { _expanded = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public ListCollectionView Items
{
    get
    {
        return _items;
    }
    set
    {
        _items = value; OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

// logic
var items = new ListCollectionView(planninglist);
items.SortDescriptions.Add(new items.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("AanZet"));
items.IsLiveSorting = true;
```

## Update

Fix based on [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771431/oneway-binding-for-togglebuttons-ischecked-property-in-wpf/3772335#3772335) suggested in the comments by @XAMlMAX.

```
public class ExpanderBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
  DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsExpanded",
                                      typeof(bool),
                                      typeof(ExpanderBehavior),
                                      new PropertyMetadata(OnChanged));

    public static bool GetIsExpanded(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsExpandedProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsExpanded(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject o,
                                  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Expander tb = o as Expander;
        if (null != tb)
            tb.IsExpanded = (bool)args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any Binding errors in the output window? Are you using `OneWay` Binding to open only one group?

Comment: This is just an example to show what I am trying to do. Binding all expanders on one property is not going to work. If I would use two way binding all expanders would open/close when I only want to open/close one.

Comment: I had similar issue long time ago and I resorted to code behind and traversal of the visual tree. I am guessing this is not something that you wanted to do?

Comment: Have you looked at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829365/2029607)?

Comment: Using the visual tree only when all else fails:) 
The SO answer you are revering to has the same trouble as I have. By binding to one value you can open/close all but not open/close one group without opening/closing the others.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772335/2029607) looks promising.

Comment: Awesome! Changed it a bit to get it to work for a Expander.

Comment: @ the person wanting this question closed, why? The question is wel constructed, with code provided, also with example of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @XAMlMAX if you add it as an answer I'll accept it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment conversation.
Reason why you were experiencing issue with expander staying open even though it was bound is because when you use `OneWay` Binding and then click on the button it then becomes disconnected. To have a better idea on when it becomes disconnected use `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High`.

To overcome this, one can use an attached property to stop Binding from detaching.
Now this example is for `ToggleButton` but the logic should apply the same.

```
public class TBExtender
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", 
                                      typeof(bool),
                                      typeof(TBExtender),
                                      new PropertyMetadata(OnChanged));

    public static bool GetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject o,
                              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ToggleButton tb = o as ToggleButton;
        if (null != tb)
            tb.IsChecked = (bool)args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Credit goes to [alex-p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52401/alex-p)
and [wallstreet-programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55143/wallstreet-programmer)
for responses on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771431/oneway-binding-for-togglebuttons-ischecked-property-in-wpf/3772335#3772335).